# IIS Express is crashing on Web app launch ( F5 )from Visual studo 17.5

Tags: visual-studio-2022, iis-express

I have installed VS2022 v17.5. When I launch my blazor wasm web application (ISExpress) then the web applicaiton is crashing on page loading .

I have checked with start without debugging option then the web app launching and working fine.

but this will not help since I want to debug my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue with the below steps,

1. Disable all the breakpoints
2. launch the web app in IISExpress
3. Once the app loaded then enable your breakpoints

this worked for me.